# Using excel tables as a source for Bokeh plot

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

How can I use an existing data table (e.g. Excel sheet) as a source for Bokeh data plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas natively supports reading from Excel sheets in to DataFrames with [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel(...)
```

And Bokeh can adapt Pandas DataFrames directly:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
```